# Update list with True/False values in function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a stock checker for a website, the code iterates thought the SKU values, checks if the item is in-stock and updates the list for the in-stock values.

I have simplified the code:

```
def check(f,b):
    #Code would check if item instock result = a
    a = False
    #Below I am trying to update value 'b', from the list 'instock' with the 'a' value.
    b[:] = list(a)


sku =['9999', '8888', '7777', '6666']
instock = [True, False, False, True]


while True:
    for f, b in zip(sku, instock):
        check(f,b)
        time.sleep(5)
```

I am having issues updating the in-stock value of a product within the function.

Current error:
    TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

How do I correctly update the instock value in the list?

My expected outcome after the code has looped through all the items in the list:

```
instock = [False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in this line ? `str(b)[:] = list(a)` it is incorrect

Comment: @shotgunner I am trying to update value 'b', from the list 'instock' with the 'a' value.

Comment: Add your expected output in your question

Comment: Updated @shotgunner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify the list use `global` keyword:

```
def check(i, item):
    global instock
    # Check if the item is in the stock or not
    a = False  # Means that item is not in stock
    instock[i] = a
```

and you don't need to use `zip()` here:

```
for k in range(10):
    for ind, v in enumerate(sku):
        check(ind, v)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you update your `check` function to return the boolean in-stock result, i.e.:

```
def check(f):
    # Code would check if item 'f' is in stock
    return False  # <-- Return the result
```

Then you can do:

```
while True:
    instock[:] = [check(f) for f in sku]
    time.sleep(5)
```